# A fast coding tip somehow ended up making the code slower in Julia

Tags: optimization, types, julia

I heard that being conscious of  type-stability contributes a lot to the high performance in Julia programming, so I tried to measure how much time I can save when rewriting the type-unstable function into type-stable version.
As many people say, I assumed that type-stable coding of course has higher performance than type-unstable one. However, the result was otherwise:

```
# type-unstable vs type-stable

#　type-unstable
function positive(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0.0
    else
        return x
    end
end

# type-stable
function positive_safe(x)
    if x < 0
        return zero(x)
    else
        return x
    end
end

@time for n in 1:100_000_000
    a = 2^( positive(-n) + 1 )
end

@time for n in 1:100_000_000
    b = 2^( positive_safe(-n) + 1 )
end
```

result:

```
0.040080 seconds
0.150596 seconds
```

I cannot believe this. Are there some mistakes in my code? Or this is the fact?

Any information would be appreciated.

### Context

- Operating System and version: Windows 10
- Browser and version: Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212（Official Build） （64 bit)
- JupyterLab version: 3.0.14

### @btime result

#### Just replacing @time with @btime for my code above

```
@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    a = 2^( positive(-n) + 1 )
end
# -> 1.500 ns 

@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    b = 2^( positive_safe(-n) + 1 )
end
# -> 503.146 ms
```

Still weird.

#### the exact same code DNF showed me

```
using BenchmarkTools

@btime 2^(positive(-n) + 1) setup=(n=rand(1:10^8))
# -> 32.435 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime 2^(positive_safe(-n) + 1) setup=(n=rand(1:10^8))

#-> 3.103 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Works as expected.

I still don't understand what is happening.
I feel like I have to know better about the usage of `@btime` and benchmarking process.

By the way, as I said above, I'm trying this benchmarking on Jupyterlab.

Comment: I'd say you're benchmarking the cost of the extra function call.

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @dratenik You don't know that this optimization is premature. I don't think that's a helpful comment to a reasonable question.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your benchmark, you testing different logic code:

`2 ^ (integer value)`
and
`2 ^ (float value)`

But the most crucial part, if `a` and `b` is not defined before the loop, Julia compiler may remove the block. Your performance very much depends was the `a` and `b` defined before and were defined in the global scope or not.

And power is the time-consuming central part of your code (not the type unstable part).

`positive` function returns `Float` in your case, `positive_safe` returns Int)

The code similar to your case (by logic) could look like that:

```
# type-unstable

function positive(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0.0
    else
        return x
    end
end

# type-stable
function positive_safe(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0.0
    else
        return Float64(x)
    end
end

function test1()
    a = 0.0
    for n in 1:100_000_000
        a += 2^( positive(-n) + 1 )
    end
    a
end

function test2()
    b = 0.0
    for n in 1:100_000_000
        b += 2^( positive_safe(-n) + 1 )
    end
    b
end

@btime test1()
@btime test2()
```

```
98.045 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2.0e8

  97.948 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2.0e8
```

The results are almost the same since your type unstable is not a bottleneck for the case.

If to test the function (which is similar to your case when a/b was not defined):

```
function test3()
    b = 0.0
    for n in 1:100_000_000
        b += 2^( positive_safe(-n) + 1 )
    end
    nothing
end

@btime test3()
```

Benchmark will show results:

```
1.611 ns
```

This is not because my laptop did 100_000_000 iterations per 1.611 ns, but because Julia compiler smart enough to understand that the `test3` function may be replaced with `nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

This is benchmarking problem. The `@time` macro is not suitable for microbenchmarks. Use the BenchmarkTools.jl package, and read the user manual. It is easy to make mistakes when benchmarking.

Here's how to do it:

```
jl> using BenchmarkTools

jl> @btime 2^(positive(-n) + 1) setup=(n=rand(1:10^8))
  6.507 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2.0

jl> @btime 2^(positive_safe(-n) + 1) setup=(n=rand(1:10^8))
  2.100 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
2
```

As you see, the type stable function is faster.

Comment: "The `@time` macro is not suitable for microbenchmarks" - why not? I tried `@btime` with OP's loops and got 1.916 ns for `positive` and 285.275 ms for `positive_safe`.

Comment: @DNF Thank you for your research. However, even if I try `@btime` macro instead of `@time`, I still get the result which says `positive` is faster than `positive_safe`.   1.500 ns for `positive`, 
  503.146 ms for `positive_safe`.

Comment: @ForceBru It's because it is noisy. The `@btime` macro was made for micro benchmarks (of execution time less than a second for example)

Comment: @ten Are you running the exact same code as the one I posted? Can you edit your question to include updated benchmarks?

Comment: @ForceBru The BenchmarkTools package takes care of compilation and warmup, chooses an appropriate number of executions, and calculates various statistics. It also allows you to interpolate variables to avoid issues with globals that can cause type instabilities. The `@time` macro does none of those things, at the very least, one must manually wrap code in functions, call the benchmark one initial time to avoid including compilation time, and use a loop to reduce statistical noise.

Comment: @DNF I was trying `@btime` on my first code by just replacing `@time` with `@btime`. As I added the question, I ran the exact same code you showed me, and I saw `positive_safe` was faster than `positive`. Is it that I wrote wrong syntax for `@btime`?

Comment: @DNF, well, OP is already using a loop. Calling `@time` multiple times to mitigate the effects of compilation doesn't change the results in this case. Furthermore, replacing `@time` with `@btime` (and even `@benchmark`) in OP's code consistently shows that calling `positive_safe` _in the loop_ takes around 290 ms, while calling `positive` takes a bit more than 2 _nanoseconds_, so `positive` is clearly _much_ faster, according to this benchmark. What's the difference between OP's new benchmark (with the loop) and the one in your answer?

Comment: @DNF I think the real questions here are: (a) Why is the original benchmark, even with `@btime`, not showing the type-stable case as faster? (b) What is the mistake in the original benchmark?

Comment: @ForceBru Compilation time is a constant addition that can influence the benchmark even if there is a manual loop. It depends on the size of the compilation time.

Comment: @BenoitPasquier I don't really know. Apparently the compiler is able to constant fold the expression for the unsafe loop, perhaps the extra function call `zero()` is somehow preventing that in the second loop. But this shows how finicky microbenchmarks can be, and that one should read the performance tips, wrap code in functions and generally be careful with over-interpreting results.

Comment: @DNF I thought so too, but, FWIW, replacing `0.0` with `0` in `positive` (making it type stable when called with `Int`s), also suffers the "bad performance" (without the `zero` barrier I thought was playing a role).

Comment: I guess it has to do with the compiler actually constant folding the expression if it figures out that the `x` in `2^x` is a `Float`... Thinking that after I tried `positive(x) = x < 0 ? 0.0 : float(x)`, which is "fast" too.

Comment: Actually I'm very confused and have no idea why this is happening :D (Replacing the range of integers with floats (`1.0:100_000_000`) and then all of them are "slow" in OP's benchmark...)

Comment: @DNF, as for "Compilation time is a constant addition" - `@time` reports compilation time if compilation occurs and doesn't report it if there was no compilation. Right? OP's benchmarks don't report compilation time, so I guess this means there was no compilation?

Comment: @ForceBru The main point of my explanation of why `@time` is not suitable for microbenchmarks was to list its weaknesses. All of them may not apply in each case. But the _first_ time the loop is run, there is compilation, and that needs to be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as Vitaliy said, is that powers in floating point done with logs can be faster than the integer ones that can be done as loop multiplies:

```
using BenchmarkTools
# type-unstable vs type-unstable

#　type-unstable
function positive_float_unstable(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0.0
    else
        return x
    end
end

#　type-unstable
function positive_int_unstable(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0
    else
        return x
    end
end

#　type-stable
function positive_float_stable(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0.0
    else
        return Float64(x)
    end
end

#　type-stable
function positive_int_stable(x)
    if x < 0
        return 0
    else
        return Int(x)
    end
end


println("unstable float")
@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    a = 2^( positive_float_unstable(-n) + 1 )
end

println("unstable int")
@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    b = 2^( positive_int_unstable(-n) + 1 )
end

println("stable float")
@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    a = 2^( positive_float_stable(-n) + 1 )
end

println("stable int")
@btime for n in 1:100_000_000
    b = 2^( positive_int_stable(-n) + 1 )
end
```

Results:

```
unstable float
1.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes) 

unstable int
179.232 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

stable float
1.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

stable int
178.990 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```